# How integrate Paypal Payment with Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby, paypal

I use this gem to integrate Paypal into Ruby [Paypal Ruby SDK](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Ruby-SDK) so everything goes perfect, now i can redirect users to my PayPal Sandbox account and the user can confirm the payment.

Once user confirm the payment it redirect back to my site with the PaymentId, Token and PayerId in the URL.

The problem is that when i want to Execute the Payment with this code

```
payment = Payment.find(@payment.id)

if payment.execute( :payer_id => params[:PayerId] )
  # Success Message
  # Note that you'll need to `Payment.find` the payment again to access user info like shipping address
else
  payment.error # Error Hash
end
```

nothing happens.

Answer (score 8):

## Standard PayPal Integration with Rails app Active Merchant gem :

### step 1:

-> add 'gem activemerchant' in  gem file

-> bundle install

### step 2:

-> Go to "www.developer.paypal.com" and create an account(also known as Merchant Account) with US address details.

-> It will create two dummy test account for buyer and seller(alias facilitator) in "sandbox.paypal.com".

Ex: 
        Seller account  --->  naveengoud-facilitator@gmail.com
     Buyer account  --->  naveengoud-buyer@gmail.com
      
-> To see test accounts details Click on "Dashboard -> Accounts"

-> Now set the password for both test accounts by clicking on profile link

### step 3:

-> Go to seller account(i.e, facilitator) profile details and copy the API Credentials i.e, Username, password and signature

Ex:
    Username:  naveengoud-facilitator_api1.gamil.com
    Password:   VSPALJ5ALA5YY9YJ
    Signature:   AVLslxW5UGzEpaDPEK4Oril7Xo4IAYjdWHD25HhS8a8kqPYO4FjFhd6A

-> Set these API Credentials in "config/environments/development.rb" as follows, add the below code with API credentials

```
  config.after_initialize do  
ActiveMerchant::Billing::Base.mode = :test         
        ::GATEWAY = ActiveMerchant::Billing::PaypalGateway.new(  
             login: "merchant_api1.gotealeaf.com",  
            password: "2PWPEUKZXAYE7ZHR",  
            signature: "AFcWxV21C7fd0v3bYYYRCpSSRl31A-dRI5VpyF4A9emruhNYzlM8poc0"  
        )  
     end
```

### step 4:

-> Form here onwards Follow the Rails cast 145 episode

## PayPal Express Checkout Integration with Rails app ActiveMerchant gem :

### step 1:

-> add 'gem activemerchant' in  gem file

-> bundle install

### step 2:

-> Go to "www.developer.paypal.com" and create an account(also known as Merchant Account) with US address details.

-> It will create two dummy test account for buyer and seller(alias facilitator) in "sandbox.paypal.com".

Ex: 
        Seller account  --->  naveengoud-facilitator@gmail.com
     Buyer account  --->  naveengoud-buyer@gmail.com

-> To see test accounts details Click on "Dashboard -> Accounts"

-> Now set the password for both test accounts by clicking on profile link

### step 3:

-> Go to seller account(i.e, facilitator) profile details and copy the API Credentials i.e, Username, password and signature

Ex:
    Username:  naveengoud-facilitator_api1.gamil.com
    Password:   VSPALJ5ALA5YY9YJ
    Signature:   AVLslxW5UGzEpaDPEK4Oril7Xo4IAYjdWHD25HhS8a8kqPYO4FjFhd6A

-> Set these API Credentials in "config/environments/development.rb" as follows, add the below code with API credentials

```
  config.after_initialize do  
ActiveMerchant::Billing::Base.mode = :test         
        ::GATEWAY = ActiveMerchant::Billing::PaypalExpressGateway.new(  
             login: "merchant_api1.gotealeaf.com",  
            password: "2PWPEUKZXAYE7ZHR",  
            signature: "AFcWxV21C7fd0v3bYYYRCpSSRl31A-dRI5VpyF4A9emruhNYzlM8poc0"  
        )  
     end
```

### step 4:

-> Form here onwards Follow the Rails cast 146 episode
Show less

-> To check weather the transaction is successful or not, just go to 'sandbox.paypal.com'  login with seller account and click on "All Activity"  then we can see the payments

Answer (score 0):

The solution that i found for this is to put this code in the page of the return URL when i configure paypal SDK

```
payment = Payment.find(@payment.id)

if payment.execute( :payer_id => params[:PayerId] )
  # Success Message
  # Note that you'll need to `Payment.find` the payment again to access user info like shipping address
else
  payment.error # Error Hash
end
```